# Downloading files in a folder selected by UIDocumentPickerController

Tags: ios, icloud-drive, uidocumentpickervc, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller, nsfilecoordinator

I'm trying to download the files contained in a folder hierarchy picked by the `UIDocumentPickerController`. I use the URL I get from `documentPicker:DidPickDocumentsAtURLs:` with an `NSFileCoordinator`.

For a folder provided by the iCloud Drive file provider, the URL it delivers in the access block is obviously a .zip file which – if files are not initially downloaded – only contains `foo.icloud` files that are archived NSURLs. How can I ensure that these files have been downloaded before the zipping process?

Am I supposed to unarchive them manually and feed them – again – into the `NSFileCoordinator`? Or do I need to use `startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:error:`? I thought using the `UIDocumentPickerController` was supposed to free me from all the manual coordination logic.

What am I missing?